# Cannot retrieve data from database

Tags: php, xampp

Good Evening,

I am trying to get the login details after the user press submit but after the button is pressed, web page not available shows up. This is the log from the error log using xampp 1.7.3:

```
[Sat Jan 07 00:49:52 2012] [notice] Child 3540: Child process is running
[Sat Jan 07 00:49:52 2012] [notice] Child 3540: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Jan 07 00:49:52 2012] [notice] Child 3540: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sat Jan 07 00:49:52 2012] [notice] Child 3540: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Sat Jan 07 00:49:52 2012] [notice] Child 3540: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sat Jan 07 00:49:52 2012] [notice] Child 3540: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Sat Jan 07 00:49:52 2012] [notice] Child 3540: Starting thread to listen on port 80
```

.

This is how i connect to the database:

```
?php
class connection
{   
    function connect($sql)
    {
        $server = "localhost";
        $myDB = "gamehutdb"; 

        //connection to the database
        $dbhandle = mssql_connect($server)
            or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server $server"); 
        //select a database to work with
        $selected = mssql_select_db($myDB)
            or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

        //execute the SQL query and return records
        $result = mssql_query($sql);

        //return result set
        return $result;
        //close the connection
        mssql_close($dbhandle); 
    }
}
?
```

Comment: Your problem is a PHP problem. Enable error reporting in PHP and check the logs, or output errors to the browser. By the way, you should report an error properly, rather than using `die()` to output an "error message".

Comment: I think the correct way is mssql_connect($servername, $username, $password), no?

Comment: how to enable error reporting using dreamweaver? i am using phpmyadmin not ms sql server

Comment: I know nothing about dreamweaver, but if you put these lines at the beginning of your php, it will print errors:
<?php ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
?>

Comment: the problem is this: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Here is a dumb question, but shouldn't you be supplying a password for the database connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with CountMurphy on PDO.

Also, from the php docs, mssql takes additional params

resource mssql_connect ([ string $servername [, string $username [, string $password [, bool $new_link = false ]]]] )

perhaps you should try supplying a username and password.

try 'root' and '' (since you aren't using a password)

try looking here
[manual for mssql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php)

Furthermore, you are using XAMPP.
XAMPP comes with MySQL. are you sure you shouldn't be using mysql_connect() instead of mssql_connect()?

Comment: Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: localhost your code doesnt work :(

Comment: I agree with Lyrae, you should be using something that can connect to mysql!

Comment: @user1114676 - I think you are using MySQL and not MSSQL. Please double check that.
If indeed you are using MSSQL, you are supplying the wrong username and/or password of the database

Answer (score 1):

For one thing your using mssql_connect, which according to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php) connects to Microsoft SQL Server.  In your comments you say you are using phpmyadmin.  Phpmyadmin only connects to MYSQL databases, not sql server.

Instead of using mssql_connect use something that connects to **MYSQL**.  Something like [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to handle your database connections (though pdo is better imo).